# The tensor $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is related to determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, tensors

My textbook says the following in an appendix on tensor notation:

> The tensor $\epsilon_{rst} = \begin{cases}
>  0 \qquad & \text{unless $r, s,$ and $t$ are distinct} \\
>  +1 \qquad & \text{if $rst$ is an even permutation of $123$} \\
> -1 \qquad & \text{if $rst$ is an odd permutation of $123$}
> \end{cases}$
>
> The tensor $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is related to determinants: for three contravariant tensors $a^i$, $b^j$, and $c^k$, one verifies that $a^i b^j c^k \epsilon_{ijk}$ is the determinant of the $3 \times 3$ matrix with rows $a^i$, $b^j$, and $c^k$.

I don't understand what this excerpt is saying:

> The tensor $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is related to determinants: for three contravariant tensors $a^i$, $b^j$, and $c^k$, one verifies that $a^i b^j c^k \epsilon_{ijk}$ is the determinant of the $3 \times 3$ matrix with rows $a^i$, $b^j$, and $c^k$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to elaborate on this and demonstrate what is being referred to.

Comment: Are you familiar with Einsteins notation of sums?

Comment: @maxmilgram I've encountered them before and scantily remember them. If you post an answer with them, as long as it's basic Einstein summation notation, I should be able to quickly review what I need to know to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the rule of sarrus for $3\times3$ matrices you find that the determinant is a sum of products of the matrix elements https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus.

The formula $a^ib^jc^k\epsilon_{ijk}$ gives exactly that: It is a sum of products of three matrix elements together with the tensor which is $0,-1$ or $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With regards to $a^ib^jc^k\epsilon_{ijk}$, is this actually Einstein summation notation? I was under the impression that the convention requires indices repeated in the contravariant and covariant positions, as in, for instance, $a^i_j x^j_i$, which would sum over all $i$'s and $j$'s? $a^ib^jc^k\epsilon_{ijk}$ doesn't have the same covariant/contravariant "alternating" pattern of indices?

Comment: Yes it is. Every index appears once as subscript and once as superscript. They do not need to be in "alternating" order.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I see: "According to this convention, when an index variable appears twice in a single term and is not otherwise defined (see free and bound variables), it implies summation of that term over all the values of the index." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! :)